# How to match and find the function calling from the string using regex in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing expressions such as calling to functions and properties:

```
$ctrl.accounts $ctrl.fn() $ctrl.fns(arg) $ctrl.foo.bar $ctrl.bay.bag() $ctrl.bar.fn(arg)
```

I made this regex that matches the word after `$ctrl.`: `/(?<=\$ctrl\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\.|\(|$)/g`. This matches the property or the function without `.` or `(`. `(?=\s|\.|\(|$)`.

The output of this string against this regex would be:

```
"accounts", "fn", "fns", "foo", "bay", "bar"
```

That's working as expected:

```js
const input = `$ctrl.accounts $ctrl.fn() $ctrl.fns(arg) $ctrl.foo.bar $ctrl.bay.bag() $ctrl.bar.fn(arg)`
const results = input.match(/(?<=\$ctrl\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\.|\(|$)/g);
console.log({ results });
```

But now I try to match only the function calls: `fn, fns`.

I removed `\s|\.` from `(?=\s|\.|\(|$)` but it doesn't work:

```
/(?<=\$ctrl\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\(|$)/g
```

For this input: `account by $ctrl.accounts`, it matches `accounts` but it shouldn't.

How I change that regex to match only functions calling, but only the function after `$ctrl.******(`?

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the following `|`,  then it will match as you wish. So remove  `\s|\.|` from 1st regex.

```js
const input = `$ctrl.accounts $ctrl.fn() $ctrl.fns(arg) $ctrl.foo.bar $ctrl.bay.bag() $ctrl.bar.fn(arg)`
const results = input.match(/(?<=\$ctrl\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\(|$)/g);;
console.log({
  results
})
```